# Are humans the only race in the Mandalorian ranks?

Tags: star-wars, races

So recently I decided to create a Star Wars D&D campaign. It starts out with the group as Mandalorian bounty hunters. However, before I make this officially start, I need to know if I can use other races for the players such as Zabraks, Trandoshans, Rodians, etc. Do Mandalorians consist of humans only or are there aliens in their ranks? If not, can there be aliens or will I have to think of a new start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choice of race will never restrict you in any way to play through any storyline in swtor.

As for story/lore/RPG i direct you to [this wiki page.](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian)

> *"An **interspecies** warrior culture stretching back thousands of years, the Mandalorians live for one purpose: to challenge the
>   greatest opponents in combat and claim victory, for honor and glory."*

Comment: This answer is about *Star Wars: The Old Republic.* The question is about a tabletop *Star Wars* campaign.

Comment: @RogueJedi If you would have bother to look at the edit history and read the big pink block that says "migrated from gaming.stackexchange.com", you would have seen that this question was originaly tagged as SWTOR and that my answer was also migrated from gaming.stackexchange

Comment: @RogueJedi Also, seeing as my answer was accepted long before you posted yours, you might have found that a hint that my answer is in the context of what the question is about

Comment: @Timelord64 He removes the SWTOR tag, thus he changes the context of the question, something that shouldn't even be done. Editing a question should only be done to make it better, not to change it. Then after my answer is accepted, he calls me out that my answer is not in the context of the question (which he changed). then he posts his own answer... and you dare call me the asshole

Comment: yeah.. If this wasnt an obvious case of wrong tag, it wouldnt have been migrated away from arqade. It would have been accepted as a standard video game lore question.

Answer (score 4):

### Legends:

In Legends, Mandalorians used to all be aliens, comprised of the [Taung](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taung).

Many different species later went on to join them.

> Here's why you can't exterminate us, aruetii. We're not huddled in one place—we span the galaxy. We need no lords or leaders—so you can't destroy our command. We can live without technology—so we can fight with our bare hands. We have no species or bloodline—so we can rebuild our ranks with others who want to join us. We're more than just a people or an army, aruetii. We're a culture. We're an idea. And you can't kill ideas—but we can certainly kill you.

- [Mandalore the Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalore_the_Destroyer)

### Canon:

Prior to Grogu, we only ever see human Mandalorians.

However, it is never explicably stated that aren't any other non-humans and no one seems perturbed by Grogu's species.

---

In the end, it's your campaign. You can do whatever you want.

Comment: "We only ever see human Mandalorians." I think that's an assumption. While it seems *likely* that the Mandalorians we see in the TV show are human based on their size/build, there are many other species of a similar size and body plan in the Star Wars Universe; it's entirely possible that one or more of the ones we've seen (especially in chaotic sequences like the firefight at the end of episode 3) are not human, as we have never seen them without full armor/helmet on.

Comment: @technophile In The Clone Wars and Rebels, we see dozens, if not hundreds, of Mandalorians without helmets and all are human.

Comment: I meant that "we have never seen [any of the Mandalorians in the television series The Mandalorian] without full helmet/armor on". Agree that we have seen Mandalorians without helmets in the two cartoon series.